# In Gaussian Process Regression, what kinds of information can you *not* put in the kernel as opposed to the mean?

Tags: gaussian-process, kernel-trick

For example, suppose you want to learn some structure for the mean and then you also have some kernel. Is is sometimes not possible to put most things in the kernel? For example, consider extrapolation properties?